# In daophot, sharpness' equation is different between python's photutils and Peter B. Stetson

Tags: python, image-processing, astropy, astronomy

In Peter B. Stetson's [DAOPHOT: A COMPUTER PROGRAM FOR CROWDED-FIELD STELLAR PHOTOMETRY](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/131977/pdf), sharpness is defined as

[image: sharp in paper]

This is the data's peak divided by the around pixel's average.

But in python's `photutils.detection.daofinder`,
sharpness is defined as

[image: sharp in python]

The numerator is data's peak minus average.

Given the sharpness is less than 1, I think minus operation should be right.

But we know that data's peak is about 0.3~0.4, avg of the neighbors are so small that won't make too much change in the minus operation.

If the denominator if the result of the deconvolution between data and a gaussian kernel, then it should approach 1.
Then the sharpness will never over 0.4.

Where did I go wrong?

I used a PSF and run it in `photutils.detection.daofinder`. The sharpness returned bigger than 0.9. But in my own code the sharpness is about 0.4:

```py
H_00 = ((gauss_kernel*psf).sum() - gauss_kernel.sum()*psf.sum()/(128*128))/\
    ((gauss_kernel*gauss_kernel).sum() - (gauss_kernel.sum())**2/(128*128))
d_avg = (psf.sum()-psf[63][63]) / (128 * 128 - 1)

d_00 = psf.max() - d_avg
sharp = d_00/H_00.max()
```

I guess the `H_00` is some how wrong, but I could not figure out how.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your code does. Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. Also, there are many different definitions for sharpness out there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.